# GeoHistogram with GeoRange fails with WeightedData

Tags: bugs, geographics

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier, fixed in 12.1.0**

---

```
positions = {GeoPosition[{30.446, -97.6482}], 
   GeoPosition[{30.446, -97.6482}], GeoPosition[{30.3898, -97.8822}], 
   GeoPosition[{30.3898, -97.8828}], GeoPosition[{30.286, -97.7639}], 
   GeoPosition[{30.1128, -97.7853}], GeoPosition[{30.3346, -97.9689}],
    GeoPosition[{30.4366, -97.6139}], 
   GeoPosition[{30.2571, -97.6118}], 
   GeoPosition[{30.3876, -97.9066}]};
weights = {1/32632, 1/32632, 1/36224, 1/36224, 1/129325, 1/14217, 
   1/48702, 1/28012, 1/20287, 1/35752};
weightedPositions = WeightedData[positions, weights];
```

This works

```
GeoHistogram[positions, GeoRange -> Quantity[3, "Miles"]]
```

This works

```
GeoHistogram[weightedPositions]
```

This fails

```
GeoHistogram[weightedPositions, GeoRange -> Quantity[3, "Miles"]]
```

with the error message

> MapThread::mptc: Incompatible dimensions of objects at positions {2,
>   1} and {2, 2} of
>   MapThread[Append,{{{-97.7639,31.8036}},{1/32632,1/32632,1/36224,1/36224,1/129325,1/14217,1/48702,1/28012,1/20287,1/35752}}];
>   dimensions are 1 and 10.

This seems like a bug. Any ideas on how to work around it?

**Update**

Reported to WRI, CASE:4220082.

**Update 2**

WRI has confirmed that this is a bug in 11.3.

Comment: I can confirm that I've seen this behaviour as well, I think it's a bug too. Notice how it functions if you give a `GeoRange` of, say, 100 miles. Similar issue in `GeoSmoothHistogram`.

Comment: This bug is still unfixed in 12.0 (I just checked).

Comment: @CarlLange Thanks for checking. That is disappointing. I have been following some of the threads on the chat regarding open source and WRI focussing on new shiny stuff while significant bugs in many areas e.g. graphs have not been fixed for a long time. I hope WRI does a 'bug fix only' release in the near future.

Comment: I have just updated my answer with a significantly better workaround - just use `Show`.

Comment: @CarlLange That is a great workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is a bug. Please report it to WRI.

A strong workaround is just to do

```
Show[GeoHistogram[weightedPositions], GeoRange -> Quantity[3, "Miles"]]
```

This functions in at least 11.3 and 12.0.

---

(The following is my old, much poorer answer)

A workaround is to filter the data for only what's going to be displayed. However, this has some issues, since the data displayed will only be on a local scale (within 3 miles, for instance) rather than a global scale (ie, all your data). If you're going to use this workaround, please don't rely on it for $\#Science$.

First, we get the centre point of your data:

```
centre = GeoPosition[Mean /@ GeoBounds@positions];
```

Then, we create a `GeoWithinQ` function to determine whether or not to include the data, with the same `GeoRange` specification we care about:

```
within = GeoWithinQ[GeoDisk[centre, Quantity[3, "Miles"]]];
```

We're going to pass an association rather than weighted data - it works the same way but it's easier to filter an association:

```
data = AssociationThread[positions, weights];
```

Finally, in our call to `GeoHistogram`, we pre-select the data to be used with `KeySelect[data, within]`:

```
GeoHistogram[KeySelect[data, within], GeoCenter -> centre, 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[3, "Miles"]]
```

It's really not great, but at least this evaluates.

[image]

Comment: Carl, Thanks for the workaround, but as you cautioned, it does not preserve the global scale. For now, I am going with `DynamicGeoGraphics[GeoHistogram[weightedPositions]]` so I can manually pan and zoom.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Yes, that's a nice workaround. It seems like there were many changes to the Geo functions in version 12, so hopefully this will be fixed in the near future.